# How to enable STRICT_ALL_TABLES' for single MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to enable STRICT_ALL_TABLES for a single MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

set sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'; will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default SQL mode by starting mysqld with the --sql-mode="modes" option, or by using sql-mode="modes" in my.cnf (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows). modes is a list of different modes separated by comma (“,”) characters. The default value is empty (no modes set). The modes value also can be empty (--sql-mode="" on the command line, or sql-mode="" in my.cnf on Unix systems or in my.ini on Windows) if you want to clear it explicitly.

ref [MySql Website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)

Comment: This set it for the whole server

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do this directly but you might get close with setting Strict for the current session when working on a particular database. Could do this in the config files of specific users.